# Форма контактов contact form 7 отправляется, даже если телефонный номер введен не полностью

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form7

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным плагином [Contact form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

В файле **formatting.php** есть функция проверки формата записи телефона

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
$result = preg_match( '%^[+]?[0-9()/ -]*$%', $tel );
return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если ввести меньшее количество цифр в тел номере, чем необходимо, то форма все равно отправляется, даже, если задать в шорткоде задано минимальное значение символов `minlength:10`

```
[tel* your-phone minlength:10 maxlength:140]
```

Почему? И как сделать дополнительную на это проверку?

Comment: Я обычно для телефона юзаю вот эту регулярку `/^((8|\+)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/i`

Comment: @Dantessss она не дает отправлять обрезанные телефоны и подставляет маску для ввода? телефоны начинаются все с 8ки?

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью другого плагина [Contact Form 7 — Маска ввода телефонного номера](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-phone-mask-field/)